# Helm get current user input

Tags: buffers, helm, minibuffer

I am trying to write a custom source for Helm. This source, however, should also give me the opportunity to create new objects, and not just select between those existing.
The problem is, when what the user entered doesn't match any object, the action I want does not get executed and no new objects can be created.

Then I tried to do the following:
Update the list of objects dynamically, adding what I have currently typed in the minibuffer to it. This should enable me to create new objects.
However, I cant seem to find any function that would allow me to actually read the input.
To illustrate:

```lisp
(defun test () (interactive) (message (minibuffer-contents)))
```

This works fine, and hitting it inside a Helm session gives me the current minibuffer input.
But when I do this:

```lisp
(helm-build-sync-source "some source"
      :candidates 'generate-candidates
      :filtered-candidate-transformer '(lambda (options source)
                                          (message (minibuffer-contents))
                                          .... some code

      :action (lambda (tag)
```

What happens is that it shows me the contents of the Helm buffer, that is, the possible selections, and **not** my minibuffer input.
Why does the same command behave differently and how can I fix it?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Please add the complete code you're using.